# Django on Apache with FCGI - 500 internal server error under high load

Tags: django, windows, apache, fastcgi

I'm using Windows Server 2008, Apache 2.2 Python 2.7 and Django as FCGI server

FCGI server is started as s service with SrvAny:

`python c:\amebas_site\amoeba\manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8881 daemonize=True method=threaded outlog=c:\amebas_site\logs\access.log errlog=c:\amebas_site\logs\error.log maxchildren=100 maxspare=90 minspare=50  maxrequests=10 debug=True`

I tried different maxspare, minspare, maxrequests and maxchildren values, but nothing helped. I always get "500 server error" under high load.

Apache config:

`FastCGIExternalServer c:\amebas_site\fcgi.hook -host 127.0.0.1:8881`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 ...
 RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /fcgi.hook/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My django website works good when there are 5-6 users online, there are no errors. 
But when I do stress-test (50 virtual users via loadimpact.com), the site shows "500 internal server error" page and I get an error message in my apache logs:

`[Thu Dec 06 16:29:48 2012] [error] [client 54.246.71.7] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : FastCGI: comm with server "C:/amebas_site/fcgi.hook" aborted: read failed
    [Thu Dec 06 16:29:48 2012] [error] [client 54.246.71.7] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "C:/amebas_site/fcgi.hook"`

But there is noting in Django logs. How can I debug this problem and get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Look, you have maxchildren=100
 1. If your request is more then 1-2seconds (possible in debug), then your server just couldn't handle all 50 connections
 2. If you have static file and it's served by django - then it also uses additional connections

Solution: you could analyse logs and calculate how many requests you have during 5 seconds for example

Comment: Static files are served by Apache. I had more than 20 request per second when there were 50 virtual users.

Comment: I'll try a larger number of child threads, but I still wonder what happens to FCGI. How to determine if it fails somewhere in processing request or just times out? Page load time also grows from 1 second to 30 seconds during test.

Comment: I tried again with maxthreads=256, but it didn't help, there are still failures (500 internal server errors) even when there is only 25 connections.